# Redefining TCL foreach

Tags: foreach, tcl

I would like to redefine TCL's `foreach`, since multiple applications of foreach break some code.

## Detailed problem description

The actual case where the code breaks happens in Vivado, a program using TCL for scripting. They supply an API that specifies `get_<someObject>` methods, which returns a list of objects (actually something that behaves like a list, but is implemented by xilinx to handle caching/printing a bit differently). To handle these lists I use `foreach`. The first time I use `foreach` on the list, I get `<objects>` in the loop variable.

However, if I apply `foreach` on a single object, the object is converted into a string representing its name. The problem is, that the API function `get_property` expects an object.

While applying `foreach` twice, does not seem to make sense, this might happen if you write two functions that take a list of objects and operate on them.

i.e.

```
proc a {obj} {
    puts "logging [llength $obj] objects:"
    foreach o $obj {
        puts "$o has column index [get_property COLUMN_INDEX $o]"
    }
}


proc b {obj} {
    foreach o $obj {
        a $o
        puts "working on $o"
        get_property COLUMN_INDEX $o
    }
}
```

If we now call these functions as follows

```
a [get_clock_regions X0Y0]   # ok (the list is turned into single objects in foreach)
b [get_clock_regions X0Y0]   # crashes inside a (the list from get_clock_regions is
                             # turned into objects by the foreach in b
                             # a is then called with a single object,
                             # the foreach now turns the object into a string
                             # representing the name, but get_property
                             # does not work on strings => error
```

I asked if the behaviour can be fixed in this [question on the Xilinx Forums](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Vivado-TCL-Community/TCL-get-broken-in-combination-with-foreach/td-p/799063), however I am looking for a workaround for the meantime.

## What I am trying to do

I would like to implement a workaround for the meantime. While I can do

```
a [list $o]
```

inside b, I think it would be nicer if I can redefine `foreach` to not break the above case. This way, I can simply drop my redefinition of `foreach` if Xilinx can fix the behaviour. (I am expecting `foreach` to work the same regardless if I have a list with one element or a single element, to my understanding this is the same in TCL).

My issues with redefining foreach are:

1. How do I know if `foreach` is called as

   - `foreach {varA varB} {valueList} {...}`
   - `foreach {varA varB} {valueList1 valueList2} {...}`
2. Is there a way to test if I have an object or a list containing one object? The Idea is two detect if it is just an object, if so wrap it into a list, which then can be unwrapped back to object by the normal foreach, however I have no clue how to detect this case.

Outline code I *would* like to write:

```
proc safeForeach {varnames valueLists body} {
    if { thereAreMultiple valueLists } {            # this issue no 1
        foreach valueList $valueLists {
            if {wouldDecayToString $valueLists} {   # this is issue no 2
                set valueLists [list $valueLists]
            }
        }
    } else {
        if {wouldDecayToString $valueLists} {       # this is issue no 2 again
            set valueLists [list $valueLists]
        }
    }
    #the next line should be wraped in `uplevel`
    foreach $varnames $valueLists $body
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of the problem is (using your example) invoking proc `a`, which expects a list, with only a single scalar value when it is called in proc `b`. Your "workaround" of invoking `a` as, `a [list $o]`, is the solution. It converts a single value into a list of one element. A list containing one element is not the same as a single value. Since lists in Tcl are just specially formatted strings, if the argument to proc `a` contains whitespace it will be treated as a list, split up into the whitespace separated components. Although Tcl is flexible enough to allow you to radically redefine the language, I think this is a case of "just because you can, doesn't mean you should." I just don't think this case is compelling enough since some code refactoring would make the problem disappear.

Comment: While I think you are partially right, you have to understand that I can't change the object or its behaviour (to stop it from decaying into a string). This leaves me with changing my code on the other end: and while you claim that lists of one object and a single object are different things, I beg to partially differ. In case of a string without spaces or a number, i cant see a difference. (`if {1 == [list 1]} {puts {where is the difference}}`), i view a string with spaces as a list of *multiple* strings, which can be dismantled by `foreach`. ...

Comment: ... However a string without spaces, stays the same no matter how often you put it through a `foreach` (`foreach a "string" { foreach b $a { foreach c $b { puts $c } } } ` will still do `puts "string"`. If they are actually different, I would be really glad to learn a way to detect the difference. I am sorry to be a bit on edge about this, but I found finding this issue quite frustrating as `puts` was not really helpful (I still saw the same output), and would like to find a workaround, that does not require future programmers to no about this fiddly detail.

Comment: I understand your frustration. This is an area where all of us have dealt with some unexpected results. But it is a consequence of the fact that strings with embedded white space, when treated as a list, convert differently than those strings with no embedded white space. It is just a "fiddly detail" of Tcl that lists are specially formatted strings and so list elements that contain whitespace require careful treatment. My usual solution is to be scrupulous about the distinction between simple values and lists along with a good chunk of useful commentary for the person coming behind me.

Comment: My biggest issue is that the string representation of the objects I am dealing with does not contain whitespace => it is indistinguishable when you do the debugging output, i.e. `puts [list $XilinxObject]` => `X0Y0` and `puts $XilinxObject` => `X0Y0`. But I guess in the end you are right and I am sstuck with cautiously rewrapping into list, and leaving comments.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, the issue is that you don't want to treat simple values as lists. One of the ways of dealing with that is indeed to use `[list $a]` to make a list out of the value that shouldn't be mistreated, but another is to change the `a` procedure to take multiple arguments so that you can treat them as a list internally while having quoting automatically applied:

```
# The args argument variable is special
proc a {args} {
    puts "logging [llength $args] objects:"
    foreach o $args {
        puts "$o has column index [get_property COLUMN_INDEX $o]"
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
a $o
```

When passing in a list to a procedure like this, you want to use expansion syntax:

```
a {*}[get_clock_regions X0Y0]
```

That leading `{*}` is a pseudo-operator in Tcl, which means to interpret the rest of the argument as a list and to pass the words in the list as their own arguments.

Comment: While I like the aprach with a *variadic argument list* (+1), this would not work, if I have to pass in two different lists or single objects, as there is no way to know where one list ends, and the other begins. What I actually would like to achieve is that `foreach var $singleObject` becomes equal to `set var $singleObject` (in case `$singleObject` is NOT a list), rather than `set var [getStringRepresentation $singleObject]`. One issue might be, that I have no Clue how the software vendor implemented an `<object>` in tcl.